# want to make this 2D comic animation smoother, but no idea how

Tags: animation, texturing, materials, 3d-view, keyframes

I've made this ultra simple keyframed animated image. I've being following alimayo arango's tutorial; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VlXALr66pLo

But it's not nearly as smooth as i'd like it to be. Examples of what i'm aiming for would be Kaptain Kristian's video on watchmen (2:23-2:32 comic animation):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5oltd-Jsi2I

All so far i've able to achieve is a simple LocRotScale keyframe to make the character's arm move but you can see the gap between the shoulder, is there a way to fix this?

Lastly, i was wondering if there were any tips, tutorials or knowledge that may help as i can't find anything related to 2D drawing animation on blender really.

Sorry if this is too broad.

cheers for any help, would mean a lot.

[image]

Comment: Before uploading your file you need to go to *File> External Data> Pack all into blend* and then save your file so that the textures will be included. Also, it would be helpful to upload a screenshot of the problem so that people might be able to see the problem quickly, without having to download the file.

Comment: Cheers for the tip, I'll get on that in the morning

Comment: You can avoid tearing/separation by using shapekeys on each limb or whatever.  There are tutorials on this.  Something to learn as a separate item/project and simple shapes to begin with.

Comment: As for the Youtube on 'Watchmen' 2:23 to 2:32, that's very easily done in Blender's 3D animation window.  Simply cut out each image on individual 2D planes and move them about, scale etc. as required, using keyframes.  Render in OpenGL for speed.

Comment: cheers ive had a crack at what you huys have said and after rendering out my animation it looks really good, so ill try and not make my future question so broad, cheers guys!

Comment: have you by any chance tried W > smooth subdivision?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rendered result looks a lot better than i thought it'd be and all i did was make the parts i wanted to animate seprated layer in gimp, import them as planes and keyframe in conjunction with using a circle plane as the parent point of rotation. Let us know if i should elaborate!